# Можно ли писать "дверь незаперта"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Слитное написание встречается  в современных текстах, например: ***К счастью, задняя дверь была незаперта. Он толкнул дверь, а она незаперта.***

В этом случае  краткая отглагольная форма должна считаться прилагательным, **но возможно ли это?**

В правилах Розенталя такое написание вроде бы не нормируется, в то же время   смотрится слитная форма **вполне приемлемо**: дверь была незапертой/незаперта.

Сравнить:

*Она приехала. Дверь была не заперта.*

*Калитка оказалась не заперта.*

Так **допускается** ли слитное написание или это ошибка?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Пример со слитным написанием "незаперта" я сначала нашла у Акунина: *Если, когда вернется из школы, **решетка все еще будет незаперта**, надо взять фонарик и забраться снова…*

Теперь я вижу, что он используется **на учебных сайтах**, где, конечно, НЕ предлагается писать раздельно. **Ведь причастие же!** Какие могут быть сомнения?

Но это всё-таки **Акунин** — писатель известный, да и книга не новая. Мог бы найти хорошего **корректора**, так нет, пишет слитно.

**Качественный признак?** А почему бы нет? Ведь незапертая дверь — это такой особый (качественный) случай, когда без ключа ее не откроешь. Вот и героя в книге волнует не действие (запрут дверь или не запрут), а как раз это самое качественное состояние.

Answer (score 2):

По смысловым причинам я не могу себе представить дверь, обладающую глубинным свойством *незапертости*, которое позволяло бы причастию переходить в прилагательное, поэтому вижу здесь краткое причастие и воспринимаю слитное написание как *ошибку* (вопрос у меня возникает не столько к современным авторам, сколько к современным корректорам, - они обязаны уметь и Си Цзиньпина записать без мягкого знака на конце).

Для сравнения: можно говорить о *незапираемости* двери в силу устройства или неисправности замка и вывести краткое *прилагательное* "**незапираема**", не связанное по  смыслу с тем, регулярно ли дверь запирают или пытаются запереть.

Comment: Спасибо. О "глубинной незапертости" я тоже пыталась размышлять, хотя называла это свойство не так изысканно, как Вы. Я думала: можно ли увидеть здесь качество, а не действие? Решила, что увидеть сложно. Но Вы слишком строги к писателям, а у них есть внутреннее чувство правильного письма. Тогда я встану на их сторону и спрошу  Вас: чем различаются варианты "дверь была незапертой/дверь была незаперта"? С чего бы это полному причастию разрешено писаться слитно, а вот краткое не может? Формы здесь близки по смыслу, взаимозаменяемы. В чем же ГЛУБИННЫЙ смысл разного подхода, как его объяснить?